# how to add voice recognition in an android app .. and use toggle button thru it

Tags: android, voice-recognition, togglebutton

i have some toggle button in my app and i need to use them with voice command . for example- if  say switch 1 on then it should toggle the switch on and on saying switch 1 off it should switch off.. feeling very helpless on this thanks for the help in advance i have no clue on it so please try to explain every thing in very detail this is the code i took from developer site to use voice recognition

```
private static final int SPEECH_REQUEST_CODE = 0;

// Create an intent that can start the Speech Recognizer activity
private void displaySpeechRecognizer() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
// Start the activity, the intent will be populated with the speech text
    startActivityForResult(intent, SPEECH_REQUEST_CODE);
}

// This callback is invoked when the Speech Recognizer returns.
// This is where you process the intent and extract the speech text from the intent.
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == SPEECH_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        List<String> results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        String spokenText = results.get(0);
        // Do something with spokenText
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use toggle switch by result of speech recognition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35461826/how-to-use-toggle-switch-by-result-of-speech-recognition)

Comment: No need to ask same question two times

Comment: This one is on how to add voice recognitions then i found that but dont know how to trigger button thru it so 2nd ques was for that