# how to use toggle switch by result of speech recognition

Tags: android, textview, togglebutton

i want use toggle switch by voice commands like switch on and switch off so i got a code for voice recognition from a site but dont know how to trigger my toggle button thru it

The code of voice recognition i used -

```
package com.authorwjf.talk2me;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

protected static final int REQUEST_OK = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
     Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
     i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "en-US");
     try {
         startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_OK);
     } catch (Exception e) {
         Toast.makeText(this, "Error initializing speech to text engine.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode==REQUEST_OK  && resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
        ArrayList<String> thingsYouSaid = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1)).setText(thingsYouSaid.get(0));



    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your array `thingsYouSaid` have all possible string array you have . for example if I say `hello` it will have like `[hello,aloe,hallo,no]` so what you have to do is you can match your string `switch off` to result string array and if it is match with like `"switch off"` than change value of your switch from on to off likewise;

```
    if (requestCode==REQUEST_OK  && resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
            ArrayList<String> thingsYouSaid = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

    for(String value : thingsYouSaid.get(0)){

    if(value.equalsignorecase("switch off")){
      // change value for switch to off

       break;
    }
    else if(value.equalsignorecase("switch on")){
    // change value for switch to on
    break;
    }


 }
```

Comment: I just copyed that code from a site i have no knowlege on java so i need the code which i can add on to the app code

Comment: thanks a lot bro ..you are an amazing guy can i contact you in personal if i need any help further in future if yes send me any contact detail like facebook id link or whats app number.. thanks once again !

Comment: i just need to add the to code right no need to add anything?

Comment: How will i refer to button by id here ?